# ImageMagick : ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a error installing the gem called rmagick. I have seen other Stack Over flow websites regarding the same issue. but din't work.

Error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170403-8836-1ebgkj8.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
        from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out

C:\Users\suresh>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170403-7540-1x6tan0.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
        from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

What i actually did, step 3 and step 4 output the same error above.

```
    1.Downloaded ImageMagick-7.0.5-4-Q16-x64-dll
    2.Set my Path to C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\include 
    set
    3.Install the gem using this command:
      gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\include
    4. or gem install rmagick
    5. Using Windows 10 machine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK GUYS I MANAGED TO INSTALL IT.

Please follow this guide.

Step 1: Download and install this

```
 ImageMagick-6.9.8-3-Q16-HDRI-x64-dl
```

Step 2: Set and create a new  Environment variable called CLASSPATH and the value set it to

```
.;C:\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16-HDRI\include;lib C:\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16-HDRI\lib
```

Step 3: gem install it

```
 gem install rmagick  --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16-HDRI\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16-HDRI\include
```

IMPORTANT TAKE NOTE!!!

when you download and install ImageMagick make sure you type the version number exactly when setting your path and gem install.

Example like ImageMagic-6.9.8-3-Q16-HDRI, follow exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`RMagick` doesn't seem to support ImageMagick 7 yet. Try to install rmagick with the latest build of ImageMagick 6.9.

Comment: i installed  7 and below. still can't

Comment: @Suresh http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ scroll down and download the **Development Kit** for your ruby